# How to label the points of a plotted function with the "only marks" property?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, axis

I am trying to draw a function in tikzpicture, that shows only specific points and to label these points.

My code looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.6\linewidth,
        xmin=-72,
        xmax= 24,
        ymin=-16,
        ymax= 40,
        x=0.1cm,
        y=0.1cm,
        xtick distance=8,
        ytick distance=8,
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$\Re z_n$,
        ylabel=$\Im z_n$,
        grid={both}]        
            
        \addplot[blue, only marks, domain=1:12, samples=12] ({sqrt(2)^(\x)*cos(deg(\x*pi/4))},{sqrt(2)^(\x)*sin(deg(\x*pi/4))});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code draws the points. Now I want to label these points. I have tried the following code, but it does not work. I hope you can help me.

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,12} 
    \draw[blue] ({sqrt(2)^(\x)*cos(deg(\x*pi/4))},{sqrt(2)^(\x)*sin(deg(\x*pi/4))}) node[above]  {$z_\x$};
```

My question is, can I add labels directly into the addplot function or do I need to write a loop that adds the labels? And what does the correct code look like.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?
With `nodes near coords*={$z_{\coordindex}$},`

**Code**

```
\documentclass[boreder=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.6\linewidth,
        xmin=-72,
        xmax= 24,
        ymin=-16,
        ymax= 40,
        x=0.1cm,
        y=0.1cm,
        xtick distance=8,
        ytick distance=8,
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$\Re z_n$,
        ylabel=$\Im z_n$,
        grid={both},
        nodes near coords*={$z_{\coordindex}$},
        ]            
        \addplot+[blue, only marks,  domain=1:12, samples=12] ({sqrt(2)^(\x)*cos(deg(\x*pi/4))},{sqrt(2)^(\x)*sin(deg(\x*pi/4))});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.